# UPDATE PHP com JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, html5

Estou tentando realizar o UPDATE, porém da o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\SitePHP\base\atualizarFuncionario.php on line 4. Segue meu código

function

```
function atualizar(id){
    if(confirm("Deseja atualizar o registro?")){
        location.href = 'atualizarFuncionario.php?id=' + id;
    }
}
```

registro.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
        <script src="JS/func.js"></script>
        <script src="JS/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p class="cab">ALTERAÇÃO DE FUNCIONÁRIOS</p>
        <form action="base/atualizarFuncionario.php" method="POST">

          <?php

             require_once './base/conexao.php';  

               $funcionario = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"id");
               $nome_alter= filter_input(INPUT_GET,"nome");
               $cpf_alter= filter_input(INPUT_GET,"cpf");
               $tel_alter= filter_input(INPUT_GET,"tel");
          ?>



  <center> <input type="text" id="inp" name="nome" size="40" value="<?php echo $nome_alter;?>" required="" placeholder="Nome" ><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="cpf" id="inp" size="40" id="cpf" required="" value="<?php echo $cpf_alter;?>" maxlength="14" onkeyup="mascCPF(this.value)" placeholder="CPF xxx.xxx.xxx-xx"><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="tel" id="inp" size="40" value="<?php echo $tel_alter;?>" id="tel" required="" maxlength="14" onkeyup="mascTel(this.value)"  placeholder="Telefone(xx)9xxxx-xxxx"><br><br>
        <a href="#" onclick="atualizar(<?php $funcionario = $_GET['id'];?>)"><button type="submit">ATUALIZAR</button></a></center>

        </form>
    <center> <a href="base/listarFuncionario.php"><input type="submit" value="Listar"</a> </center>


    </body>
</html>
```

atualizarFuncionario.php

```
include_once './conexao.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
$telefone = $_POST['tel'];
$atualizar = "UPDATE funcionario SET nome='$nome', tel = '$telefone', cpf= '$cpf'  WHERE id= '$id'";

$atualizar = $PDO->query($atualizar);


if($atualizar){
    echo "<script>alert('Funcionario atualizado com sucesso!');  </script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Erro ao atualizar'); </script>";
     //location.href = '../formCadastro.php';
}
```

Comment: indique qual código é referente ao arquivo registro.php, para facilitar

Comment: O do meio, onde contém meu formulário

Comment: ok vou editar a pergunta, aceite a edição para eu corrigir alguns detalhes

Comment: method="POST" você está enviando o form como POST E esperando o parâmetro como GET, isso mesmo?

Comment: Sim, pois quando coloco para receber o parâmetro como POST ele da erro

Comment: Cara, você enviar POST e tentar pegar GET não faz menor sentido. Nunca vai dar certo

Comment: e esse `base/`, tá certo esse METHOD do FORM??

Comment: Sim, é o caminho do meu arquivo atualizarFuncionario.php

Comment: Repare que não precisa indicar a página qual irá no seu type=submit, ele já reconhece isto pelo action, siga meu código que dará totalmente certo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não faz sentido o JavaScript ali, você não precisa usar ele, basta colocar um campo hidden no seu formulário como o id que vai atualizar e enviar como "POST" mesmo para o PHP, ficaria assim:

registro.php:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
    <script src="JS/func.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <P class="cab">
               ALTERAÇÃO DE FUNCIONÁRIOS
            </P>
            <form action="base/atualizarFuncionario.php" method="POST">

                    <?php
        require_once './base/conexao.php';            
        $funcionario = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"id");
        $nome_alter= filter_input(INPUT_GET,"nome");
        $cpf_alter= filter_input(INPUT_GET,"cpf");
        $tel_alter= filter_input(INPUT_GET,"tel");
        ?>



  <center>
    <input type="text" id="inp" name="nome" size="40" value="<?php echo $nome_alter;?>" required="" placeholder="Nome"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="cpf" size="40" id="cpf" required="" value="<?php echo $cpf_alter;?>" maxlength="14" onkeyup="mascCPF(this.value)" placeholder="CPF xxx.xxx.xxx-xx"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="tel" size="40" value="<?php echo $tel_alter;?>" id="tel" required="" maxlength="14" onkeyup="mascTel(this.value)" placeholder="Telefone(xx)9xxxx-xxxx"><br><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" size="40" value="<?php echo $funcionario?>" id="id" >
    <button type="submit">ATUALIZAR</button>
</center>



            </form>
        <center> <a href="base/listarFuncionario.php"><input type="submit" value="Listar"</a> </center>


        </body>
    </html>
```

e o php:

```
include_once './conexao.php';
$id = $_POST['id'];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
$telefone = $_POST['tel'];
$atualizar = "UPDATE funcionario SET nome='$nome', tel = '$telefone', cpf= '$cpf'  WHERE id= '$id'";

$atualizar = $PDO->query($atualizar);


if($atualizar){
    echo "<script>alert('Funcionario atualizado com sucesso!');  </script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Erro ao atualizar'); </script>";
     //location.href = '../formCadastro.php';
}
```

Comment: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de '1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' ce' Ã  la ligne 1 in C:\wamp\www\SitePHP\base\atualizarFuncionario.php on line 10

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de '1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' ce' Ã  la ligne 1' in C:\wamp\www\SitePHP\base\atualizarFuncionario.php on line 10

Comment: Consegue enviar a mensagem de erro do SQL?
os dados inputados?

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="id" size="40" value="<?php echo $id = $_GET['id'];?>" id="id" > editei essa linha e consegui enviar as informações ao banco

Comment: E deu certo o UPDATE

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou bastante!

Comment: Eu tinha errado o nome da variável, agora editei e está correto. @RuanRodrigues

Answer (score 2):

Alterei seu formulário e seu `POST` e o que estou enviando é um código funcional, ou seja, foi testado antes de postar aqui. Repare que retirei o `href` do seu `type='submit'` pois se já está sendo indicado no `<form action='...'` já é reconhecido o arquivo a qual ele tem que submeter os dados

```
<form action="atualizarFuncionario.php" method="POST">

    <?php

    require_once './base/conexao.php'; 

        $funcionario = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"id");
        $nome_alter= filter_input(INPUT_GET,"nome");
        $cpf_alter= filter_input(INPUT_GET,"cpf");
        $tel_alter= filter_input(INPUT_GET,"tel");

    ?>

    <label>ID: </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $nome_alter; ?>" required>

    <label>Nome: </label>
    <input type="text" id="inp" name="nome" size="40" value="<?php echo $nome_alter; ?>" required="" placeholder="Nome"><br><br>

    <label>CPF: </label>
    <input type="text" name="cpf" id="inp" size="40" id="cpf" required="" value="<?php echo $cpf_alter; ?>" maxlength="14" onkeyup="mascCPF(this.value)" placeholder="CPF xxx.xxx.xxx-xx"><br><br>

    <label>Telefone: </label>
    <input type="text" name="tel" id="inp" size="40" value="<?php echo $tel_alter; ?>" id="tel" required="" maxlength="14" onkeyup="mascTel(this.value)"  placeholder="Telefone(xx)9xxxx-xxxx"><br><br>

    <center><input type='submit' name='enviar' value='ATUALIZAR'></center>

</form>
```

E o código para alterar ficou desta forma, criei um banco e aqui funcionou perfeitamente, onde irá ser verificado se existe o `ID` do funcionário para fazer `UPDATE`, caso contrário, ou seja, caso não exista ele fará `INSERT`

```
include_once './conexao.php';

    if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){

        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
        $tel = $_POST['tel'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM funcionario WHERE id = '$id' "; 
        $resulta = $conn->query($sql);
        $row = $resulta->fetch_assoc();

        if ($resulta->num_rows > 0) {
            $result = "UPDATE funcionario SET nome = '$nome', cpf = '$cpf', tel = '$tel' WHERE id = '$id' ";
        } else {
            $result = "INSERT INTO funcionario (nome, telefone, endereco) VALUES ('$nome, '$cpf', '$tel')";
        }

        $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);
        echo $result;
     }
```

Comment: Só esqueceu de colocar o value no hidden lá, mas é isso ae!

Comment: já foi editada a resposta, mas obrigado @arllondias